# Is programming a master password a good idea for a PHP based login system?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I have an area of my system where clients can login to view information about their account. The login system is secure (I hope) and uses the latest PHP standards (e.g. `password_hash`, `password_verify`, etc).

There's often the need for me to login to a client's account for a variety of reasons but obviously I don't know their password (and I don't want to know it either). Would it be safe for me to program a master password that allows me to login to any account using the same password?

I would like opinions on ethics, affect on security, etc.

**EDIT**

Both the clients access and my access is read only.

Comment: Maybe implement a permission based system?

Comment: If the clients are aware, then I guess so. This is opinionated.

Comment: There's nothing in the client area that we can't already see (or don't already know), it's basically a mirror of our platform but they can only see limited information.

Comment: I would.  Call it an Admin account, or something.  Give it the same permissions as the owner.  Give them the password too, if they want it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - I couldn't give them the master password as this would allow them to login to any user's account.

Comment: Remember, the only thing that stops users logging in is a bit of PHP code. As an admin or SuperAdmin you can allow yourself to see anything. This is one reason we hash passwords, so that us SuperAdmins cannot see a real password even in this situation

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thanks, are there any effects on security?

Comment: I wish people would comment rather than just head straight to downvote :(

Comment: You could create some sort of account switcher in your admin dashboard, you pick a user and do the PHP magic to log you in to that account without the need of a password. You could use your own password only to log into your account, and then use a password only to enter this switching area. It's safer than using a secondary password in the login screen. This would make it easier for yourself, just list the users and pick one to login to. But remember that it's not ethical to wander around your user accounts.

Comment: You would have to make sure that teh SuperAdmin account password was good and strong and Never Shared

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against it.

Even though the risk might seem minimal, what if a user some how comes across this master password? Then you've compromised your whole system.

I would say there are two separate approaches you could take here.

1. Copy your hashed password over theirs in the database, should there be an issue with a specific account. Then ask them to reset their password when you've completed troubleshooting.
2. Create admin functionality to login as any user.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned this in my question but both the clients access and my access is read only.

Comment: Access to the DB is read only?

Comment: Yes, the client can only view information

Answer (score 0):

Impersonating real people is a bad idea. You're basically doing stuff from their name, and they know it. They can use that against you, when one of them does a mistake or intentionally does some harm. They can legitimately blame you for doing it, and you DO have the access to do this.

No.

At all times, have them log in to their account from their computer, while they're looking, using VNC software that they have to start manually. Record the session in a video, in an archive if you have to. Don't allow any windows for anyone to incriminate you. Don't trust anyone. All people are nice and good until you get stabbed in the back. Don't allow this.

If you want to just test certain features, create test accounts with various credentials, to emulate interaction on isolated parts of the database.

I can't stress this enough: You are a programmer. Your only responsibility should be to create code that works. Once you give other people access to modify stuff, you should isolate yourself as much as possible from that process. Through documents that absolve you from responsibility, to security walls outside of your control, that prevent you to act directly on the production database without someone else's approval, in order have legitimate defense in case anyone tries to blame you for their f**k-up.

**Ideal solution**:

- Have a staging environment where everybody has access, including developers, where features are tested
- On Production:

  1. You must not have any ability to modify anything without logging in to the production servers. Not via GUI, not from the DB, not anything.
  2. Every time you need to update something on production, log in (make sure the system logs your session start), while you're recording on video what you're doing.
  3. After you've done your changes to production, have a second person that is NOT a developer, or someone who won't have a conflict of interest, validate that a certain version is on production (you must not have admin access to version control either).
- When something doesn't work for someone, use one of these solutions:

  1. Have them start VNC or similar software that allows them to watch. Have them log in, you help them do their stuff, then exit and get away as far as possible again.
  2. Prepare an isolated data set for some isolated users. These users must not be aware of the rest of the DB, and the rest of the users must not be aware of the isolated part of the database. These isolated users should mimic the credentials of all the rest of the user groups you have. This should allow you to replicate, test scenarios.
  3. Always have an active logging system, that logs errors, exceptions, and virtually everything that's not a huge security risk to log. These logs should be accessible to you at any time. They are another of your tiny windows into Productions that you should be limited to.
  4. Have history tables in the database for any sensitive content. Have a robust code that allows you to impersonate another user, but everything done by that impersonated user should be logged in the database. Don't use this super-user under any circumstance except written request, or some other physical or electronic document that you can use to protect your back. That document should clearly state what changes are requested, and you should never do anything besides what's explicitly requested. NEVER.

Because in my experience, when anything goes wrong, the first one to get the blame is the programmer, and if the programmer can't justify why it's not his fault, then he may have a serious problem. Most of these times people are reasonable and believe you when you say you had nothing to do with it, but you just don't want to get unlucky.

Comment: They can mess up and try to put the fault on him. A way to prevent this is to keep track on when the user login, but not track when the 'master password' is used. Then he would have this against the user. He'd save the time of login in a separate table for example.

Comment: Or even better track if the login was made by user or master password. God, I'm a genius!

Comment: He still needs to record the session, in video, each time he does that. Or have the software versions strictly controlled, and have it store change history by the user that did that, together with a flag whether it's impersonated or real. Yeah, solutions are many, but the easiest one is just to keep away as far as possible from this. Develop locally, test on staging, release on production under heavy supervision, and keep as far away as possible from production the rest of the time.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned this in my question but both the clients access and my access is read only.